# Assign a task to 1 or many users - how to find out the task completer?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, tasks

I created a workflow which uses the Create Item In List action to assign tasks to users to complete (such as fill in new employee details in a task form). The workflow is using the Assign To field to send tasks to 1 to many people.

I have 2nd workflow running on the task list of Workflow 1 and when task is complete it sends out email notifications to users. In these emails I list the outcome of the task and who completed it. When Assigned To was set to allow only 1 user completing the task it was easy to get the completer. Now, however, I don't know how to get the user who completed the task besides creating a new person field for the completer and asking the user to complete a task to enter their own name.

Could anybody suggest a smarter solution? Is there a workflow action or SP non-custom field to take the

Comment: If Workflow 2 detects when a Task is complete then the user who triggered that Workflow 2 was the one who approved it? If so his/her info is in the standard Workflow properties (or Modified By field)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the "Start a task process" action to create the tasks, rather than creating the task list items manually. This will let you assign the tasks to the users you need to, and the outcome will be stored in a workflow variable. You can set the task options so that the workflow will wait until the tasks are complete, and then you can have a "Send an email" action in the same workflow to send the outcome.

If you need different outcomes than the default (Approved/Rejected), you can create a new task content type with the outcome values that you need.